# Execute bash command and capture output

Tags: perl

I have a bash command I'm executing in perl as follows

```
 @args = ( "bash" , "-c",  "diff <(ssh  -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" user-db01 'mysql -uuser -ppass --execute=\"show databases\"') <(ssh  -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" user-db02 'mysql -uuser -ppass --execute=\"show databases\"')");
system(@args);
```

but this doesn't allow me to get the output to a string variable. 
If I execute the exact samething with backticks

```
 $cmd = "bash -c diff <(ssh  -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" user-db01 'mysql -uuser -ppass --execute=\"show databases\"') <(ssh  -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" user-db02 'mysql -uuser -ppass --execute=\"show databases\"')";
 my $res = `$cmd`;
```

its throwing an error `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('` What can I do to execute the command and get the result in a variable?

Comment: What is the sample code and the exact error from backticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the usual CPAN modules, e.g. [`IPC::System::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple) that has a `capture()` method; or a more-likely-to-be-present [`IPC::Open2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html).

Your backticsk problem is that you didn't quote the diff command, thus making it an argument to bash:

```
BREAKS: bash -c diff <( cmd2 ) <( cmd1 )
GOOD  : bash -c "diff <( cmd2 ) <( cmd1 )"
```

Your code treats every "word" as a separate argument to your system shell (NOT to bash), e.g. it's the same as calling `system("bash", "-c", "diff", " <(ssh" ...)`

Comment: When I do a $cmd = "cmd" and then  backtick `$cmd`, the double quotes within cmd are causing problems even if they are escaped

Comment: @Aks - you need to escape the escapes, most likely. A highly annoying excercise, so you should look into CPAN options in my answer.